# Emacs button doesn't work after saving, closing and re-opening the file

Tags: emacs

I added the following code to my .emacs to create a button when Shift-F10 is pressed:

```
(require 'button)
(global-set-key (kbd "<S-f10>")
                (lambda ()
                  (interactive nil)
                  (insert-button 
                   "Open and search file." 
                   'action (lambda (x) (find-file "~/org/bib.org") (isearch-forward)))
                  )
                )
```

When I press Shift-F10 in a buffer containing a file, the button does get inserted, the label is highlighted and it works properly. However, if I save, close and re-open the file, then the button label is not highlighted and the button doesn't work.

Why doesn't it work after the file is closed and re-opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A button inserted into a buffer is not persistent, even if you save the buffer in a file.